# How to move artifact from repo X to repo Y using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, artifact

How i can move artifact in Jfrog Artifactory from source repo to a target repo using jenkins pipeline.

I found this [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-PromotingBuildsinArtifactory) for a copy methode.

Please advise, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The command you found is relevant. The promotion idea is meant for copying or moving between repositories. Just need to toggle the `copy: true` or `copy: false` for copying or moving.

You can also use the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) that has a [move command](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-MovingFiles) for moving files between locations in Artifactory.

In general, the CLI is your swiss army knife for almost all operations agains Artifactory in an automation friendly way.